# SharePoint Person Column lookup check fails when I add some simple jquery to form

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, active-directory, customization

I have a sharePoint list form I've reinserted into a page as custom add mode.  That list has a people picker person type column.  the form works great until I add some jquery code to default another another dropdown column.  Now the when I enter a name into the person column and hit enter it never return an underline to confirm person is valid - i just get the processing icon.  Here's the jquery code which otherwise works. We are on MOSS 2007 SP2

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('select[title$=Issue Type] option:eq(0)').text("Please Select").val(""); 
</script>
```

Full code block after noconflicity() change :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery.noConflict(); 
jQuery('select[title$=Issue Type] option:eq(0)').text("Please Select").val(""); 
$('select[title$=Issue Type]').change(function(){
  var issue = $('select[title$=Issue Type] :selected').text();
  var bodyprefixes = [];
  $('#issuetbl td:contains('+issue+')').nextAll().each(function(i, k) {
   bodyprefixes.push($(k).html().replace(/DIV/g,"\n").replace(/&nbsp;/g,"\n").replace(/<[^>]+>/g, ""));

  });
  $('input[title$=Subject]').val(bodyprefixes[1]);
  $('textarea[title$=Message]').val(bodyprefixes[0]);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors on the console?  I don't see how this could affect your people picker.

Comment: The people picker itself works, it's the person check. After it picks the person, it's freezes processing too. We are on 2007 sp2. No console error that I can see. The code works, but the people picker textbox just spins processing. I've started with a fresh empty form, add the control - it works, then I add this code and the people search check does not validate. Seems like a bug or conflict.

Comment: Does it work if you only add the first line (the jquery include)?

Comment: Try using straight javascript instead of jquery.

Comment: If I comment the Please Select line and add a var x = 1; line the people picker works. I suspect it will work in javascript. odd.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is jQuery's use of the $ is colliding with something SharePoint is doing.  Why don't you try the jQuery's noConflict mode: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
jQuery.noConflicy();
jQuery('select[title$=Issue Type] option:eq(0)').text("Please Select").val("");
```

Comment: That change does not change the dropdown and rest of jquery code is not running. I don't see console errors.

Comment: the code works to set the dropdown, but still got issue with people column and now rest of code does not do anything. updated question. Thanks.. appreciated.